# Settings file instance name

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I create a settings file, Visual Studio generates a singleton with the instance name Default:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.SettingIHaveSaved
```

How can I get Visual Studio to generate another list of settings with a new instance name? Say,

```
Properties.Settings.Debug.SettingIHaveSaved
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get Visual Studio to generate this property but you can easily add this behavior.  `Settings` is implemented as a partial class so you just need to create a new file with another partial declaration and add the property you want there.

For example

```
internal partial class Settings {
  private static Settings _debugInstance = ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Settings());
  internal static Settings Debug { 
    get { return _debugInstance; }
  }
}
```

Comment: I figured I could do this but it takes away use of the Settings interface provided by Visual Studio :/

Comment: @Jake, howso?  I've done this technique several times and the settings designer continues to function

Comment: How can I use the Settings interface to change the settings used by Settings.Debug? All of the changes made to the interface only affect Settings.Default.

Comment: Apparently you can't. Thanks!